# How to get properties for large models hosted on BIM 360 Docs? Response is "diagnostic: Failed to query the data"

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We have a construction client with a couple of very large models hosted on BIM 360 Docs, and we’re trying to download the properties.  For the 2 largest files, we’re getting a response from that endpoint that says “diagnostic: Failed to query the data.”

We are using this endpoint to retrieve the properties;
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/

I did see this post about using the objectID to query for properties for a specific object.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-objectid-query-parameter-model-derivative-properties-api

Unfortunately we need all of the properties so it would not be practical for us to poll the server for every item in the entire hierarchy.

Is there anything I can do to get around this or is it a restriction on the Model derivative service that can be addressed from the Autodesk side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties can be obtained in a couple of ways. Using the [GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) endpoint works for most cases, but it may not be the best choice if there's too much data in your design, or if you need the data in their original form (for example, without concatenating values and units into strings).

Another option is fetching the properties in form of a sqlite database, or as a collection of gzipped JSON files (usually used by Forge Viewer). All the options are explained in this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer.

Comment: In the sqlite there is a data_type column, that contains an id of the type. In your post you don't uncover how one could get human readable property type using sql query. If I got it right, it's the same enum as AttributeType from [PropertyResults](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/globals/PropertyResult/). But I can't find its definition, the closest I found is [this](https://autodesk-forge.gitee.io/viewer-docs/global.html#AttributeType). Is it correct way to decode this value?

Comment: Seems like there is a better place to find documentation for this enum (https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/global.html#AttributeType). Took me time to find it

Comment: If someone else have this question, this is how you could get property values with their human readable types https://gist.github.com/DimGun/0dc7368293b9aff95207a5fc53e0fedc